# What does C=il mean/stand for in OpenSSL and this error?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

When I verify one of Firefox's certificates I get the following:
[image: dd]

I know what CN and O is, but I don't know what C=IL is. Nor do I understand the error I get. Can somebody please tell me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`C` in a DN is country code, so `C=IL` is `Country=Israel`.

Error 18 means that the cert was badly generated, or is not configured properly on your host, so it's hard to diagnose that error message without more context. It found a self-signed root certificate (ie "0 depth"), but was not happy about it for whatever reason.

My immediate guess is that you need to add this root cert to your OS trust store. The OpenSSL Verify will try and chain the cert you provide back to a cert in your trust store. If it can't, then you'll get an error message like the one above.

---

EDIT addressing comments:

The OP exported a cert from Firefox's trust store and is attempting to verify it using openssl. The root cert that it chains to is not in the OS's trust store, so openssl is reporting: A) error: cannot establish trust in the root, but B) the cert is otherwise cryptographically valid.

Comment: I just downloaded the certificate from my Firefox's certificates and when I verify it gives me that error

Comment: AHH, that makes sense. Firefox keeps its own list of root certs that it trusts, independantly from the OS's trust store. OpenSSL does not have access to Firefox's trust list, so can't chain the cert back to something trustworthy.

Comment: So that's why it gives me the error? But it says OK after?

Comment: I didn't write openssl, so I don't know exactly what that `ok` is supposed to mean. Maybe it means that all the signatures are ok?

Comment: It means that the certificate is issued by a CA

Comment: [`man verify`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html) describes the verify operation.  The important sections are `VERIFY OPERATION` and `DIAGNOSTICS`.  In summary, the verify operation succeeds because of the following line: `If a certificate is found which is its own issuer it is assumed to be the root CA.`.  (1) the errors pops out, which means that a root certificate could not be found, (2) the highlighted rule takes place and the processing continues, (3) verification succeeds as a CA certificate.

Comment: @grochmal In other words, that openssl output means "This is a self-signed root CA cert, but I have no idea if I should trust it or not."   .... ?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth - yep, pretty much that.

Comment: @grochmal So the problem is that Firefox keeps its own listof root certs that it trusts independantly from the OS's?

Comment: @user126233 - There isn't a problem, really.  It is just the way FF installer choose to do it.  On Linux it is different for example, most distro packagers will point the FF build to the OS's certs.  MS Windows is a beast where applications normally come bundled as a whole and dependency chains are unheard off.  So FF choose to take add a group of CA certs with its installation (and several DLLs that are not strictly part of FF too).

Comment: @grochmal I get the error because the root certificate could not be found? Is that the problem or why do I get the error?

Comment: @grochmal I understood that it was deeper than that - FF (and Chrome) want to control their own CA approval and revocation processes. For example, see: wiki.mozilla.org/CA:How_to_apply. Also see this: Mozilla is currently in the process of revoking the certs of some naughty CAs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C6BlmbeQfn4a9zydVi2UvjBGv6szuSB4sMYUcVrR8vQ/mobilebasic

Comment: @user126233 It may or may not be a problem, depending on what you're trying to do. So what are you trying to do? Firefox trusts the cert, but your OS (and openssl) doesn't. End of story, don't worry about it. If this is a problem for you, then install ComSign's root cert into your OS (there are tons of articles on google for how to do this).

Comment: Just want to verify the certificate with OpenSSL :)

Comment: lol, well you can't :P

Comment: Have I understood this correctly; I get the error as OpenSSL doesn't trust the cert but FF does, and I get OK as the verification was successful?

Comment: @user126233 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth - Well, that may work on platforms where FF has control over how it is installed.  I'm posting this from an FF that has not been built by the mozilla guys.  I'm on arch where you *can* meddle with the FF certs.  If you look at the [FF package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/firefox/) and the [mozilla-certs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/testing/x86_64/ca-certificates-mozilla/) they have no dependency on each other and you can use a FF with your own certs from the package manager :).  You cannot force someone to use certain certs at application level.

Comment: @user126233 - The `ok` stems from the fact that the signature inside the cert could be verified by the public key inside the cert (it is not corrupted for example).  But that does not imply absolutely anything about trust.  Trust stems from the fact that something that you already trust did sign it (which isn't the case, since it signed itself).